# Too slow to Download USB bootable Ubuntu program

Tags: usb, downloads

I wonder why its takes over 11 hours to download the file: ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
I'm in China and using VPN, if no VPN it will force me to a Chinese site which gives China's own Ubuntu. Sorry I'm comfortable with English. Any clue to speed it up. Thanks in advance.
Raja

Comment: Have you tried multiple mirrors located close to the VPN endpoint you're connecting to?

Answer (score 3):

If it is possible for you to download via the torrent, you should do so.  I found I was able to download the latest 14.04 iso [via bittorrent](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) very quickly compared to downloading directly from the web site.

Comment: Download it and verify the md5 checksum from http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS and you should be good to go.